# Wordpress Custom Post Type - ACF in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have some problem that I need help in them -

I register custom post type - is slug is "project"

But I need to make 3 categories (with ACF) and make url changed due to it

category1 = http://www.example.com/mycaturl/nameoftitle

category2 = http://www.example.com/othercat/nameoftitle

category3 = http://www.example.com/customedit/nameoftitle

How can I make it without plugins...?

Thanks for helpers :)

Answer (score 0):

***Tested and verified:***

I am writting in steps to make it clear:

1. Make sure when you registered your custom post type `rewrite` for more: [register custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/%project_categories%','with_front' => FALSE),`

2. Then register your taxonomies  **project_categories**

You need to register custom taxonomy  **project_categories**  for this custom (**project**) post type. `register_taxonomy` please [read here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for more

```
function project_taxonomy() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'project_categories',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
        'project',        //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'project store',  //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'project', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false //  Don't display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'project_taxonomy');
```

3. Last make, your post type liks filters.

   ```
   function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
    {
       if ($post->post_type != 'project')
           return $link;

       if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_categories'))
           $link = str_replace('%project_categories%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
       return $link;
   }
   add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
   ```

**Note:** if you see post not found error. then change your permalink settings to *default* and save changes. And again set permalink to *Post name* and it will work.

Comment: hey - thanks for the fast comment, but how I choose taxonomy for each post?

Comment: You need to add your 3 categories in the backend and assign to those posts when you like category in normal posts

Comment: I see the categories choose in the backend, but it doesn't change the url... all posts are still /project/name-of-project

Comment: Go to your permalink settings and add `/%category%/%postname%`